# Offer animation - Blender or some other program

Tags: animation

I know this question is not directly related to Blender but I don't know where else to ask it.

I am working in a small company which should make a presentation of an assembly line that we have constructed in 2D and 3D CAD software.

The presentation should look something like the ones from the next links

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fpdeLxUBPk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFEQJBHdn0U

1) Is Blender good enough to make something like this? 
I should present line to non-technical educated people so I only need to show them concept instead of details.

2) I am thinking of hiring someone from UpWork community or similar sites (I don't have time to learn modeling in Blender), do you have a better idea?

Best regards!

Comment: This is indeed considered offtopic here, https://blenderartists.org would be a better place to ask. There is even a section for paid work if you consider hiring. There is also https://www.blendernetwork.org for hired work. In anyway Blender seems more than capable and an adequate tool for that type of work, depending on the skills of the artist and available time you may easily achieve better quality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about hired work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to answer in comment, but, seems would be better to answer directly.

1. Blender is more than good enough for this.
2. a) You have to decide if you want an interactive or a video.
   b) You have various options for costing, if that is the issue! You requirement seems quite possible for interactivity
   c) You can also have basic **interactivity with a number of videos** and have a web based application.
3. **If you plan to hire**, Blender or any other tool should not matter (it depends on the tools used by the one whom you have hired. But please support blender :))
4. For 3d interactivity you have options on web and/or app, there are technologies and engines for webgl (blender2web,threeD.js) and for apps Unity3d, UE4 and more.
   **I'll recomend App over Web for 3d**.
5. Make sure you have more than cad drawings for the person developing this, a video of the process would be more useful than cad design and text.
6. You can try various forums as Blender forums, Unity forum, Ue4 for people and teams who provide you with 3d services. Do understand if its onetime work or something you want further development.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. No.5 could be a problem since this should be a video for a project demonstration so we can get a contract. I have little assemblies produced so I can test critical spots, but I cannot produce without customer funding.

Comment: **Some reference**, even if its loosely related would help. Also cad can be annotated to be more artist readable :) . But either way, all these only help out, **but not a necessary requirement**, so things would workout even without  references.

Answer (score 1):

Blender is good for this type of presentations.

You can make video like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L__2suWPk9s

or interactive 3D-presentations like this (using addon blend4web): 
https://www.blend4web.com/apps/dairy_plant/dairy_plant.html?v=9e5dd2c40ed17b48ebd949bf7f8d9d0c

Comment: Thank you for fast reply.
I love both representations, but I think the second one is out of my budget.
How long would take someone to build animation like first video?
Best regards!

Comment: @TomislavHorvat I've made it in one day